# How to route local traffic over WiFi and everything else using the mobile data interface on android?

Tags: android, linux, routes, root, iproute

I have a rooted android 13 phone(oneplus 10 pro) and at home I have a local WiFi network used for smart home devices NAS and CCTV this network is not connected to the internet.

If I connect to this network using my phone I'm able to access my local devices but browsing the web becomes impossible because all traffic is routed over the WiFi network interface (network without internet access) by default on android when connected to a wifi network.
I want my phone to route traffic for local IP's (192.168.1.x) over the WiFi network interface (Wlan0) and route all other traffic using the mobile data interface (rmnet_data2).

I tried multiple thing but I haven't found a reliable solution to get this to work, I hope someone can assist me with this.
below are some of the things I did while trying to get it to work, I had some success but can't get it to work reliably.

**#1. Mobile data always active**
First I enabled the developer setting "Mobile data always active" to make sure both the WiFi and mobile data adapters stay enabled simultaneously when connecting to a WiFi network.

**#2. USB debugging and shell**
I enabled USB debugging and connected my phone to my PC so I can open a shell to execute commands on my phone (android uses the linux kernel).
using command prompt and adb I connected to my phone and opened a shell:
`$ adb shell`
next I elevated it to a root shell
`$ su`

**#3 change routing stuff**
Checking the current routing rules.
`$ ip rule list`

Checking the routing table
`$ cat /proc/net/route`

Checked the routes for local and public ip's using the ip route get command
`$ ip route get 10.10.10.10`
`$ ip route get 192.168.1.135`

Added a rule for the local IP's, to use wlan0 with router IP as gateway
`$ ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0`

route everything else using mobile connection
`$ ip route add default dev rmnet_data2`

Comment: This should be already possible with Stock Android 13: "Concurrent local-only and internet connection" https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-sta-sta-concurrency Not sure if your phone supports that.

Comment: @Robert My phone does support Wi-Fi STA/STA concurrency (which allows devices to connect to two Wi-Fi networks concurrently.) This is not what I'm looking to accomplice I do not have two WiFi networks. I have a mobile connection and a local WiFi network.

Comment: The main purpose of Wi-Fi STA/STA are two Wifi connections, however the case `Concurrent local-only and internet connection: The device connects to a local-only network without disrupting the device's primary internet-providing connection.` sounds to me like a combination of Wi-Fi and mobile data.

Comment: @Robert Assume you are correct (I'm still not convinced) how do I use it. To me it looks like it is documentation for app development so you can create an app that can register / configure IOT devices using wifi without loosing internet access while doing so. I'm not developing an app, I want to force traffic over a specific interface depending on the destination IP system wide.